# Shell compare and mark

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have 2 files list.txt and fail.txt. Its a list of test cases and failed test cases. I need to mark failed against the test cases which appear in fail.txt in the list.txt. I need it in shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without you sharing the format of your files, here's a guess:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {failed[$1]; next} 
    ($1 in failed) {print "failed: " $0; next} 
    1
' fail.txt list.txt > marked.txt
```

---

update:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {failed[$1]; next} 
    {
      status = ($1 in failed) ? "Fail" : "Pass"
      print $0, status
    }
' fail.txt list.txt > marked.txt
```

Comment: Or `printf "failed: "` without the `$0; next`.

Comment: Thanks Glenn and Dennis - It works, but I want to add the failed at the last. And also append Pass for ones not found.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should investigate the `join` command?

```
sed 's/$/ FAIL/' fail.txt |
join -a 1 -e PASS -j 1 -o 1.1,2.2 list.txt -
```

#### list.txt

```
/work/supernova/alpha/net-nsf.c
/work/supernova/alpha/net-nsf.h
/work/supernova/alpha/nsfpipe.c
/work/supernova/alpha/sqcrypto.c
/work/supernova/alpha/sqlmutil.c
/work/supernova/alpha/squtil.c
/work/supernova/beta/scb.h
/work/supernova/delta/delta-init.c
/work/supernova/delta/delta-pseudo.c
/work/supernova/delta/onvproc.c
/work/supernova/gamma/mt-aio.c
/work/supernova/gamma/mt-aio.h
/work/supernova/gamma/mtblk.c
/work/supernova/gamma/mt.c
/work/supernova/gamma/mtdll.c
/work/supernova/gamma/mt.h
/work/supernova/gamma/mt-info.c
/work/supernova/gamma/mtm.h
/work/supernova/gamma/mtpool.c
/work/supernova/gamma/mtpseudo.c
/work/supernova/gamma/session.c
/work/supernova/gamma/session.h
/work/supernova/omega/jlm.c
/work/supernova/omega/osenv.c
/work/supernova/omicron/mivp.c
```

#### fail.txt

```
/work/supernova/alpha/net-nsf.c
/work/supernova/alpha/net-nsf.h
/work/supernova/alpha/sqcrypto.c
/work/supernova/beta/scb.h
/work/supernova/delta/delta-init.c
/work/supernova/delta/delta-pseudo.c
/work/supernova/gamma/mt-aio.c
/work/supernova/gamma/mt-aio.h
/work/supernova/gamma/mtblk.c
/work/supernova/gamma/mt-info.c
/work/supernova/gamma/mtpool.c
/work/supernova/gamma/session.h
/work/supernova/omega/jlm.c
```

#### Output

```
/work/supernova/alpha/net-nsf.c FAIL
/work/supernova/alpha/net-nsf.h FAIL
/work/supernova/alpha/nsfpipe.c PASS
/work/supernova/alpha/sqcrypto.c FAIL
/work/supernova/alpha/sqlmutil.c PASS
/work/supernova/alpha/squtil.c PASS
/work/supernova/beta/scb.h FAIL
/work/supernova/delta/delta-init.c FAIL
/work/supernova/delta/delta-pseudo.c FAIL
/work/supernova/delta/onvproc.c PASS
/work/supernova/gamma/mt-aio.c FAIL
/work/supernova/gamma/mt-aio.h FAIL
/work/supernova/gamma/mtblk.c FAIL
/work/supernova/gamma/mt.c PASS
/work/supernova/gamma/mtdll.c PASS
/work/supernova/gamma/mt.h PASS
/work/supernova/gamma/mt-info.c FAIL
/work/supernova/gamma/mtm.h PASS
/work/supernova/gamma/mtpool.c FAIL
/work/supernova/gamma/mtpseudo.c PASS
/work/supernova/gamma/session.c PASS
/work/supernova/gamma/session.h FAIL
/work/supernova/omega/jlm.c FAIL
/work/supernova/omega/osenv.c PASS
/work/supernova/omicron/mivp.c PASS
```

As long as the files are in sorted order, should work like a charm.  If you don't want the PASS marks, then omit the `-e PASS` argument pair.  If you want a different FAIL mark, adjust the `sed` script.  If you want a different order for the output columns, alter the `-o` option.

Comment: Jon I am working on Hamilton shell and join does not work here. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Zack: the `join` command is independent of the shell you use - it is a regular Unix command like `sed`.  However, it may not be on your machine, even so, in which case it is no help.  It is a slightly eccentric way to solve the problem - though it is also perfectly effective.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to have a go with `grep` and its `-f` and `-v` option

```
grep -v -f file1 file2
grep -v -f file2 file1
```

Comment: The `-v` has to come before the `-f`.